# C# code timing in production

Tags: c#, performance, production, stopwatch, measurement

I wish to implement switchable code timing facilities in my production code, the idea being that when performance issues are occurring on a user machine the performance logging can be turned on to provide useful data to indicate where issues are.

To this end my logic would be to have a factory class that would implement a bool property TrackPerformance and a method GetPerformanceTracker that returns either of NullPerformanceTracker or LoggingPerformanceTracker that implement an IPerformanceTracker interface.

The Null is obviously there to do nothing and the other would write out to a Log4Net logger which could potentially be split out from the normal logging if required. I'd use the StopWatch class for timings. So far so good.

**The issue?**

How best to implement this without it overly affecting performance itself?
I'm thinking of using compiler services attributes on a MarkElapsedTime method as

```
MarkElapsedTime(string message, [CallerMemberName] callerMemberName = "", [CallerLineNumber] int = 0)
```

Instantiating a timer at method level seems sub-optimal due to the number of factory calls. It therefore seems to be preferable to instantiate this at a class level, in which case I need to tie the MarkElapsedTime call to the relevant Start() call in order to measure the correct amount of elapsed time.
Loosely

```
class LoggingPerformanceTracker:IPerformanceTracker
{
    private readonly ILog mLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(....);

    private readonly StopWatch mStopWatch = new StopWatch();
    private readonly Dictionary<int, TimeSpan> mElapsed = new Dictionary<int, TimeSpan>();
    private int mNextId = 0;

    public void MarkElapsedTime(int timerId, string message, [CallerMemberName] callerMemberName = "", [CallerLineNumber] int = 0)
    {
        var ts = mStopWatch.Elapsed.Subtract(mElapsed[timerId]);

        if (mLogger.IsInfoEnabled)
            mLogger.Info(string.Format("{0}: {1} - [{2}({3})]", message, ts, callerMemberName, callerLineNumber));

    }

    public int Start()
    {
        if (!mStopWatch.IsRunning)
            mStopWatch.Start();

        var key = mNextId;
        mNextId++;
        mElapsed.Add(key, mStopWatch.Elapsed);

        return key;
    }
}
```

I've not had to do this before and given that these measurement calls would be placed all over the codebase in key areas I'd ideally like to get it right first time.
Also is the use of the Log4Net logger a good or bad idea - I obviously need to see the data at some point whether that means logging in memory then dumping or sending to file straight off.

Comment: A good longer-term approach that you may like to consider is the use of a dependency injection framework - like Castle Windsor, Ninject, etc - to give you the functionality you need. The advantage is that you do not need to put performance calls all over the code base and you can use a config file to change whether or not the measurement code is injected at run-time. You can then also inject new measurement code by adding extra assemblies without the need to recompile your production code.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I'm not sure I understand where you're coming from with this. Forgive my naivety but I would have thought DI into the class constructor vs Factory call within constructor to reference the performance class at a class level wouldn't affect where I'd need to place calls for measurement. Surely if I want to measure performance in a switchable manner I'm still left with var id = IPerformanceTracker.Start()...code...IPerformanceTracker.MarkElapsedTime(id, "XYZ") constructs all around the codebase am I not? It's just a matter of whether it's calling the null or real instance.

Comment: Unless of course you are referring to interception? I should have stated before that this is for a library using ExcelDNA in which case sheet-based functions are implemented as static functions so I need a way of doing this that covers both instatiated and static classes.

Comment: No, with dependency injection you do not need to have `var id = IPerformanceTracker.Start()...code...IPerformanceTracker.MarkElapsedTime(id, "XYZ")` around in your codebase at all. That's the point of DI. It's also not interception. You would use the decorator pattern to add timing code. If you can wait I can put a basic answer to show you the approach.

Comment: I added an example of using dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's how to do some dependency injection to solve this issue.

First, let's just say we have this code:

```
public class DoSomeWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

It's piece of code that performs some (potentially) long running task.

We might call it like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doSomeWork = new DoSomeWork();
        doSomeWork.Execute();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Now, to add logging I could go thru the code base and add code like this:

```
public class DoSomeWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

But this means that if I want to add logging code to the entire code base I'm editing a lot of files and making my code more complicated.

There is a way to make this work without adding the logging code to each file.

To start with we need to introduce an interface with the `Execute` method to abstract the code we're calling.

```
public interface IDoSomeWork
{
    void Execute();
}
```

Now the `DoSomeWork` class looks like this:

```
public class DoSomeWork : IDoSomeWork
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Now the calling code looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = Context.CreateRoot();
        context.SetFactory<IDoSomeWork, DoSomeWork>();

        var doSomeWork = context.Resolve<IDoSomeWork>();
        doSomeWork.Execute();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Now, I've used a dependency injection framework that I wrote for this, but you could use Castle Windsor, Ninject, etc.

The line `Context.CreateRoot()` creates a dependency injection container. The `context.SetFactory<IDoSomeWork, DoSomeWork>()` configures the container to know that when I ask for an instance of `IDoSomeWork` to actually return an instance of `DoSomeWork`.

The line `var doSomeWork = context.Resolve<IDoSomeWork>()` asks to container to try to resolve (create or return) an instance of an object that implements `IDoSomeWork`.

From there the code runs like the original code.

Now I can write a logging class that "decorates" the concrete class.

```
public class DoSomeWorkLogger : IDoSomeWork, IDecorator<IDoSomeWork>
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        this.Inner.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    public IDoSomeWork Inner { get; set; }
}
```

This class implements `IDoSomeWork` as well as a special interface `IDecorator<IDoSomeWork>` required by my container to allow this class to act as a decorator.

So now the calling code looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = Context.CreateRoot();
        context.SetFactory<IDoSomeWork, DoSomeWork>();
        context.SetDecorator<IDoSomeWork, DoSomeWorkLogger>();

        var doSomeWork = context.Resolve<IDoSomeWork>();
        doSomeWork.Execute();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The line `context.SetDecorator<IDoSomeWork, DoSomeWorkLogger>()` now tells the container that there is a decorator for the `IDoSomeWork` interface.

So what now happens when the line `var doSomeWork = context.Resolve<IDoSomeWork>()` is called is that an instance of `DoSomeWork` is created like before, but also an instance of `DoSomeWorkLogger` is created. The `Inner` property of the `DoSomeWorkLogger` instance is set with the instance of the `DoSomeWork` and the `DoSomeWorkLogger` instance is returned from the `Resolve` method.

So now when the `doSomeWork.Execute()` method is call then the logger code is run which in turn calls the actual execute code.

The `DoSomeWork` code doesn't need to change for me to add the logging functionality.

Now this code as it stands isn't perfect yet as we have all of the `SetFactory` and `SetDecorator` code that would create dependencies that we want to avoid.

So here's how we get around it.

First the `IDoSomeWork`, `DoSomeWork`, and `DoSomeWorkLogger` code are moved into three separate assemblies.

Then `DoSomeWork` and `DoSomeWorkLogger` have two special attributes added. They look like this:

```
[Factory(typeof(IDoSomeWork))]
public class DoSomeWork : IDoSomeWork { ... }

[Decorator(typeof(IDoSomeWork))]
public class DoSomeWorkLogger : IDoSomeWork, IDecorator<IDoSomeWork> { ... }
```

Now I can change the calling code to this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = XDocument.Load(@"fileName");
        var context = Context.LoadRoot(config);

        var doSomeWork = context.Resolve<IDoSomeWork>();
        doSomeWork.Execute();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The container is now configured using an XML file. The format of the XML isn't important, but what is is that it can be changed without recompiling the code. So by changing the XML to not include the assembly that the `DoSomeWorkLogger` class is defined in will effectively remove the logging. Add that assembly and instantly the logging code is added back in with no recompilation necessary.

Simple. :-)

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it is a thorough example of a method of solving the problem and should prove helpful to others. After reading this and honing my search terms somewhat I was able to locate an example of what I am trying to achieve using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) with this [Code Project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS)

Comment: @Mark - Fair enough. It's good that you found another alternative.